# What environment architecture to choose to verify multi-interface module

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I'm going to test complex module which have axi4-stream and apb interfaces as inputs and axi4 interface as output.
As I understand, I should build this kind of environment:

```
                                      |-----------------------------------------------
                                      |                                              |
                             _________|_________           _______________     ______v______
                            |                   |         |               |    |            |
                            |   APB-monitor     |         | AXI4-monitor  |--->|            |
                            |___________________|         |_______________|    |            |
                                       |                          |            |            |
 ____________        ______________    |     _________            |            |            |
|            |      |              |   |    |         |           |            |            |
| APB-seqr   |----->| APB-master   |---*--->|         |           |            |            |
|____________|      |______________|        |         |           |            |            |
                                            |   DUT   |           |            |            |
 ____________        ______________         |         |-----------*----------->| Scoreboard |
|            |      |              |        |         |                        |            |
|AXI4-S-seqr |----->|AXI4-S-master |---*--->|         |                        |            |
|____________|      |______________|   |    |_________|                        |            |
                                       |                                       |            |
                                       |                                       |            |
                             --------------------                              |            |
                            |                    |                             |            |
                            |   AXI4-S-monitor   |---------------------------->|            |
                            |____________________|                             |____________|
```

Is it correct? If so, how should I send transactions from monitors to scoreboard? I guess I should use analysis_port/imp pair but I can't overload `write` method in scoreboard class, so as I understand, I can't use three analysis ports in one class.
Can anyone point me to uvm example of such a complex design?
Currently I have this type of error when try to use analysis ports:

````
#    Time: 0 ps  Iteration: 0  Region: /uvm_pkg::uvm_analysis_imp #(axi4_s_pkg::axi4_s_seq_item, ecaa_pkg::ecaa_scoreboard) File: D:/questasim64_10.4c/win64/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/uvm_pkg.sv
# ** Error: (vsim-8754) D:/questasim64_10.4c/win64/../verilog_src/uvm-1.1d/src/tlm1/uvm_analysis_port.svh(114): Actual input arg. of type 'class work.axi4_s_pkg::axi4_s_seq_item' for formal 'trans' of 'write' is not compatible with the formal's type 'class work.apb_pkg::apb_seq_item #(3, 2, 32, 32, 4)'.```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways of solving your problem.

**1. The Easy Way (Using `uvm_analysis_imp_decl Macros)**

Simply invoke the macro outside of the component class for each input. The macro declares a special flavour of analysis imp. The argument passed to the macro is used as a suffix within the type name of the imp and the name of the write method. You then instantiate one imp per input and define one method per input. eg:

```
`uvm_analysis_imp_decl(_AXI4_S)
`uvm_analysis_imp_decl(_AXI4)
`uvm_analysis_imp_decl(_APB)

class scoreboard extends uvm_scoreboard;

  uvm_analysis_imp_AXI4_S #(AXI4_S_xact, scoreboard) AXI4_S_export;
  uvm_analysis_imp_AXI4   #(AXI4_xact,   scoreboard) AXI4_S_export;
  uvm_analysis_imp_APB    #(APB_xact,    scoreboard) APB_export;
  ...
  function void build_phase(uvm_phase phase);
    AXI4_S_export = new("AXI4_S_export", this);
    AXI4_export   = new("AXI4_export",   this);
    APB_export    = new("APB_export",    this);
  endfunction
  ...
  function void write_AXI4_S(AXI4_S_xact t);
    ...
  endfunction

  function void write_AXI4(AXI4_xact t);
    ...
  endfunction

  function void write_APB(APB_xact t);
    ...
  endfunction
  ...
```

**2. The Hard Way (Embedded Subscribers)**

Instantiate three subscribers inside your scoreboard. Each is a separate scope, so each can have its own `write` method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually, I thought about 2nd way, and I have subscribers in test environment for single interface modules. It would be great to reuse them, but they have such write method: `function void write(axi4_s_seq_item t);
        axi4_s_scoreboard axi4_s_sb;
        $cast(axi4_s_sb, m_parent);
        axi4_s_sb.write(t);
    endfunction` for axi4_s interface. I can't use them because of same reason and I'm not sure that it good practice to write new subscribers for a new combination of interfaces.